# Calculating true anomaly of a hyperbolic trajectory from time

Tags: orbital-motion, simulations

I'm creating a simulation for orbiting bodies with my primary challenge being calculating the true anomaly of a trajectory with respect to time. I have figured out circular, elliptical, and parabolic orbits, but i'm struggling with hyperbolic.

Everything I have found in my searches provides equations relating true anomaly v, to hyperbolic anomaly F, but nothing to determine F on its own.

The closest i've found to a solution is from [this site](http://www.braeunig.us/space/orbmech.htm#hyperbolic). With the equation [image] But deriving a solution was a little beyond me.

Can anyone help me find or derive the equations to calculate the true anomaly of a hyperbolic trajectory with respect to time? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the same as the elliptic case, except:
$$ t = \sqrt\frac{a^3}{GM} (\theta - e\sin(\theta))$$
becomes:
$$ t = \sqrt\frac{a^3}{GM} (e\sinh(\theta)-\theta)$$

and
$$ \nu = 2 \arctan\left( \sqrt{ \frac{1-e}{1+e} } \tan\left( \frac \theta 2 \right) \right)  $$
becomes:
$$ \nu = 2  \arctan\left( \sqrt{ \frac{e+1}{e-1} } \tanh\left( \frac \theta 2 \right) \right) $$